# Bind Custom Properties to LoggingEvent Object in Log4Net

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net, fluentd

I am using `log4net` and I am trying to figure out the best way, or if there is anyway, to bind custom fields to the `LoggingEvent` object, that is used in the `Append` override method of the `AppenderSkeleton`.

For example, this could be a `guid` property to add to the other properties such as `level`, `renderedMessage`, etc.

However, I am planning on using the `Log4net.Appenders.Fluentd` with the `log4net.Ext.Json`, so the appender in the `xml` would look something like this:

```
<appender name="Fluentd" type="Log4net.Appenders.Fluentd.FluentdAppender, Log4net.Appenders.Fluentd">
    <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
    <Port>24224</Port>
    <Tag>YourTagHere</Tag>
    <NoDelay>false</NoDelay>
    <ReceiveBufferSize>8192</ReceiveBufferSize>
    <SendBufferSize>8192</SendBufferSize>
    <SendTimeout>1000</SendTimeout>
    <ReceiveTimeout>1000</ReceiveTimeout>
    <LingerEnabled>true</LingerEnabled>
    <LingerTime>1000</LingerTime>
    <EmitStackTraceWhenAvailable>true</EmitStackTraceWhenAvailable>
    <IncludeAllProperties>false</IncludeAllProperties>
    
  <!--json formatted log4net logging-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
    <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
    <member value="date:date" />
    <member value="level:level" />
    <member value="message:messageObject" />
  </layout> 
</appender>
```

I was hoping there would be something like this in the end:

```
<!--json formatted log4net logging-->
<layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
    <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
    <member value="date:date" />
    <member value="level:level" />
    <member value="message:messageObject" />
    <member value="guid:guid" />
</layout>
```

Is this something I would have to some how carry out in the `Log4net.Appenders.Fluentd` source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ThreadContext` to add a custom property to the `LoggingEvent` object that is passed into the `Append` override method of the `AppenderSkeleton` and the `Format` override method of the `LayoutSkeleton`.

Set it:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["my_custom_prop"] = "my custom property"
```

Then retrieve it:

```
var prop = evt.GetProperties()["my_custom_prop"].ToString();
```